# How do I store the json string after a JsonReaderException?

Tags: c#, .net, json, model-view-controller

In the service layer, when parsing a JSON string, if the parsing fails a `JsonReaderException` gets thrown to the controller.

```
JObject jData = new JObject();

try
{
    jData = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
}
catch (JsonReaderException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

In the controller, which is in the web layer, after catching that exception I want to store that JSON string in the database along with the exception message.

```
catch(JsonReaderException ex)
{
    _exceptionLogService.LogException(new ExceptionLog()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now,
        Message = ex.Message,
        Content = "json string (response.Content) goes here"    
   }
}
```

I could do this in the service layer (and that's how I initially did it), however, due to dependency injection, I would have to add a dependency to `_exceptionLogService` and then change the code in a lot of places. I'm looking for a simpler quicker way to do this in the web layer, if possible. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So save the response.content!

Comment: How do I send it to the controller with the exception?

Comment: Your controller isnt talked about in your code, so ive no idea.  If your second portion of code, make a new exception of your own that takes a parameter for the json string, so you can pass it along

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your controller isnt talked about in your code, so ive no idea. If
>   your second portion of code, make a new exception of your own that
>   takes a parameter for the json string, so you can pass it along –
>   BugFinder 2 hours ago

I solved this problem by creating a custom `JsonParseException` that takes a `JsonReaderException` and a string as paramters, and throwing it to the controller. Unfortunately I cannot mark a comment as an answer.

```
JObject jData = new JObject();
try
{
    jData = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
}
catch (JsonReaderException ex)
{
    throw new JsonParseException(ex, response.Content);;
}
```